# Mac users can copy and paste, but can't drag and drop using ExtremeZ-IP

Tags: network-shares, smb, afp

When mounting a Windows Share using afp:// (via ExtremeZ-IP) users cannot drag and drop files, but they can copy and paste.

If the share is mounted using smb:// they have no problem.

Anyone have any ExtremeZ-IP experience, reasons for this, solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was found when narrowing down some old ACL's that were left floating around in AD. The users strangely had the correct effective permissions though, but something about those ACL's was getting in the way. As soon as I removed or updated them, everything works as expected now.

Comment: The real reason this is happening is because the security group in Windows needs the advanced permission of "delete subfolders and files". You are correct because by applying a new ACL group it probably added this permission. I've been able to reproduce this issue, solve it, and reproduce it by adding and removing this permission.